# Convert initializer_list of pointers to vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, unique-ptr, initializer-list

I created this class, which represents a set of shapes:

```
class CompoundShape : public Shape {
    private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> shapes;

    public:
    CompoundShape(std::initializer_list<Shape *> shapes) : shapes(shapes) {}

    void draw() {
        for_each(shapes.begin(), shapes.end(), [](auto &shape) { shape->draw(); });
    }
};
```

The class `Shape` has another child class, `SimpleShape`. Ideally, I'd want to initialize a `CompoundShape` like this, without having to worry about freeing the pointers to the shapes afterwards:

```
CompoundShape shape = {
    new SimpleShape(...),
    new SimpleShape(...),
    new CompoundShape{...},
    ...
}
```

The only problem, I think, is in the `CompoundShape` constructor, where I try to do `shapes(shapes)` which of course doesn't work, because a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>` can't be initialized with a `std::initializer_list<Shape *> shapes`.

What would be the best way of achieving this conversion?

Comment: `shapes(shapes.begin(), shapes.end())` ? You should name your private member variables with some kind of member variable designator (such as a leading`m_` or trailing `_`).

Comment: `shapes(shapes.begin(), shapes.end())` doesn't solve the issue, although I'll take the member variable designator suggestion into account.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/hqdn3a this works

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: That was my bad, I had tried to change something else in the code, and that's why it didn't work, you were correct

Comment: Even when you solve this, your biggest concern will be the complete *lack* of exception safety in your chain of constructions. As the list is being built each resulting raw pointer has yet to be managed by a `std::unique_ptr` instance. The result is that any one of those constructors that tosses will immediately leak any fully constructed predecessors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sad that we cannot use `std::initializer_list<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>`.

You can still use constructor of vector taking 2 iterators to do the (not so explicit) conversion:

```
CompoundShape(std::initializer_list<Shape *> shapes) : shapes(shapes.begin(), shapes.end()) {}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3564c7e5582c85b)

vector constructor would do something similar to

```
template <typename T>
template <typename It> // SFINAE to avoid to conflict with vector(std::size_t, T) when T=size_t
std::vector<T>::vector<T>(It begin, It end) :
    m_size(std::distance(begin, end)),
    m_capacity(m_size),
    m_data(allocate<T>(m_size))
{
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it, ++i) {
        new (&data[i]) T(*it); // placement new, calling constructor deferencing iterator
    }
}
```

So in your case

```
std::initializer_list<Shape *>::iterator it /* = .. */;
Shape* shape = *it;
new (&data[i]) std::unique_ptr<Shape>(shape);
```

Comment: This works, although I don't understand what happens behind the scenes. How are the raw pointers converted to `unique_ptr`s?

Comment: @cabralpinto implicit construction of `std::unique_ptr<Shape>` In the case of single-args, they're often called *conversion construction*.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That constructor is `explicit`, but vector calls it explicitly under the hood.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not the constructor he's asking about (or so I believe). I think/thought he is/was asking about conversion from `Shape*` to `std::unique_ptr<Shape>`.

Comment: @WhozCraig: [std::unique_ptr's constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) #2, I don't see other candidates.

Comment: @Jarod42 And that changes what, exactly, about what I thought the OP was asking?